# Change input tag value on click or alternative method?

Tags: php, html

I some PHP code which prints rows of data from a Trade table. each row is like

username - offer - exchange - date - trade

TRADE is a input, and when clicked, does the relevant PHP checks and updates database accordingly.

if POST etc.

```
$idn=strip_tags($_POST['buy']));

$query1=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tradeauction WHERE id=:buyid");
$query1->execute(array(':buyid'=>$idn));
```

///checks etc..

this is the div containing the TRADE input/button :
(I know this is probably a really long way of doing it, but its old code, and I'm simply  trying to neaten it up and convert the whole site from mysql to PDO.)

```
        <div class="buyrow left">
        <?PHP echo"<input class=\"changeBlue\" onmouseover=\"this.className='changeBlueoff'; document.getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlueoff'\" 
    onmouseout=\"this.className='changeBlue'; getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlue'\" 
onclick=\"this.value='$ct->id'; this.submit()\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Trade\" name=\"buy\">"; ?> &nbsp; 
       </div>

    $ct->id
```

is obviously the id of the row.

the class changes simply change the color of the button.

When clicked currently, it works, but briefly displays the id to the user. I dont want this to happen. I just want it to simply say trade all the time. (and blue when hovered)

How can I make the value NOT show when clicked, but still pass the id value through to the PHP checks? or can someone suggest an alternative, easier way to achieve this?

edit: for each ID (row) in the tradeauctions, it will print in HTML -

```
<div id="cashtrades">
  <div class="trrow left"> <?php echo "<a href=profile.php?viewuser=$ct->username >$ct->username</a>"?></div>
  <div class="prrow left"><?PHP echo"$showname"; ?></div>
  <div class="ofrow left"><?PHP echo"$symbolcheck".makecomma($ct->item_amount)." $itemcheck"; ?> </div>
  <div class="exrow left"><?PHP echo"$exsymcheck".makecomma($ct->exchange_amount)." $exitemcheck"; ?></div>
  <div class="darow left"><?PHP echo"$ct->datepost"; ?></div>
  <div class="buyrow left"><?PHP echo"<input class=\"changeBlue\" onmouseover=\"this.className='changeBlueoff'; document.getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlueoff'\" 
          onmouseout=\"this.className='changeBlue'; getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlue'\" 
          onclick=\"this.value='$ct->id'; this.submit()\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Trade\" name=\"buy\">";?>&nbsp;</div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is the id of your user echo'd into the html, I can't see it in your code?

Comment: there is no user id. 

$ct->id is the id of the row containing the trade details in the database.

Comment: Ok I understand.  Can you write a javascript function to set the value of a hidden input item instead and use that in your php code instead of the input you are updating?

Comment: ok, i see. so instead of the `this.value`, I would, in theory, replace that with `getElementById('hidden').value`

but in a much neater way with a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).  You'll find it will revolutionise your interaction with javascript.  If you are unsure what all the {}(){()} mean search for Douglas Crockford and watch his videos.

That said.

```
<div class="buyrow left"><?PHP echo"<input class=\"changeBlue\" onmouseover=\"this.className='changeBlueoff'; document.getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlueoff'\" 
      onmouseout=\"this.className='changeBlue'; getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlue'\" 
      onclick=\"this.value='$ct->id'; this.submit()\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Trade\" name=\"buy\">";?>&nbsp;</div>
```

try

```
  <div class="buyrow left">
// this is a new hidden input with the buy id 
<input type=hidden name=buy id=buyinput value=<?php echo $ct->id ?> >

//onclick Submit
<?PHP echo"<input class=\"changeBlue\" onmouseover=\"this.className='changeBlueoff'; document.getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlueoff'\" 
      onmouseout=\"this.className='changeBlue'; getElementById('$ct->id').className='changeBlue'\" 
      onclick=\"this.submit()\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Trade\" name=\"anotherbuy\">";?>&nbsp;</div>
```

It's very difficult to read this code and I think you should do this another way, but whats above should solve your problem.